# How to match a text for any other characters in between

Tags: regex, excel-formula, google-sheets

I want to match a text, which should return true even if

user enters

```
BackOrdered
BAck ordered
B ack ordered
Back-ordered
backordered
BaCkOrdeRed
```

or any which has a similar meaning

I have tried with

```
=REGEXMATCH("Back ordered", "^[a-z A-Z]*$")
```

but my regular expression takes Someabcd also as true. I need to get true only if "backordered" word is present (can contain spaces between ie b a c k o r d e r e d should be true)

Comment: You can try with this regex `/^b ?a ?c ?k[ -]?o ?r ?d ?e ?r ?e ?d$/ig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[\s-]*b[\s-]*a[\s-]*c[\s-]*k[\s-]*o[\s-]*r[\s-]*d[\s-]*e[\s-]*r[\s-]*e[\s-]*d$
```

It's basically this:

```
^backordered$
```

but with `[\s-]*` (zero or more whitespace or hyphen) added in between each letter.

And you should turn on the case insensitive option.

[Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/W79m2X/1)

Comment: What if upper case?

Comment: @CodeGuy there should be a case-insensitive option. Is there not in excel?

Answer (score 1):

If your environment is Excel and the user input is in cell **A1**, then in cell **B1** enter:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),"-",""))="backordered"
```

[image]